# Subsets of intervals

Tags: real-analysis

If *S* $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}$ is a nonempty, bounded set, and *I* := [inf *S*, sup *S*], show that *S* $\subseteq$ *I*.  Moreover, if *J* is any closed bounded interval containing *S*, show that *I* $\subseteq$ *J*.  To show that *S* $\subseteq$ *I*, let *x* $\in$ *S*.  Since *S* is bounded, inf *S* $\lt$ *x* < sup *S*.  Thus *x* $\in$ *I*.  Therefore *S* $\subseteq$ *I*.  Is this correct?  I feel like I am missing something.  How do I show that *I* $\subseteq$ *J* if *S* $\subseteq$ *J*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that $\inf S < x$; for example, if $S = [0, 1]$ and $x = 0$, this is false. What *is* true, and follows directly from the definitions, is that
$$\inf S \le x \le \sup S$$
since $\inf$ and $\sup$ are actually bounds on $S$. The result follows immediately from this observation.

---

For your second question: Suppose $S \subseteq J = [a,b]$. Argue that $a \le \inf S$, so that $a$ is a lower bound for $I$. Make the same argument for the upper bounds.